# RStudio not showing output in Console when using a variable?

Tags: r, output, rstudio, rstudio-cloud

Currently learning RStudio but for some reason my Console isn't outputting my code? Not sure if there was a setting I may have toggled but it seems to only affect me when I have a variable in my code?

For example:
when working the ToothGrowth dataset

```
data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowth)
```

This executes and I can view the table of the data in a separate tab.

However, when I try to filter it

```
data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowth)

filtered_tg = filter(ToothGrowth, dose=0.5)
View(filtered_tg)
```

Nothing Returns, a formatted table doesn't open and an empty line is returned in the console window.

This is just one example, even when i try something as simple as

```
number = 10
number
```

I would expect, in return;

```
[1] 10
```

But console is empty.

Looking for solutions online, I've seen maybe i didn't close a bracket or parenthesis and to include CloseAllConnections() if there was a '+' showing in the console (which there isn't).

Working on rstudio cloud so is there a reset somewhere that I could possibly try?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score -1):

I changed the function as follows:

```
filtered_tg = filter(ToothGrowth, dose=="0.5")
View(filtered_tg)
```

After running these commands it was viewed as the table of the data in a separate tab

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP3LS.png)